# Code Reuse : Common Functions - Laravel

Tags: php, api, laravel

I'm in the process of Developing APIs for a System whose front end is Android.  App calls the API with `lat` and `lon`.

I am using Laravel for this and have developed some APIs already.  I've also created separate controllers for each and is working correctly.

However 2 (*Calculate Distance from Latitude and Longitude and return nearest ones in Ascending order*) of the functions are used commonly almost in 3 or 4 Controllers:  `BusinessController` , `OfferController`, `OutletController`.  I thought it would be better to reuse the code passing parameters correspondingly.

Where should I place the common functions and how should they be invoked?  Here is the code for `controller.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesCommands;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController {

    use DispatchesCommands, ValidatesRequests;

}
```

PS: I'm somewhat new to Laravel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Laravel 5, the *App* folder is autoloaded. Create a folder or just a file somewhere in it:

```
<?php

namespace App; // Or App\Yourfolder

class YourSpecialClass
{
   // Your methods
}
```

And in your controller, just simply `use App\YourSpecialClass;`

Comment: Thanks for Clarifying